# How to Implement UITextView inside UITableView inside UITableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift

how to implement UITextView inside UITableView inside UITableView ??

[image]

(1) If you type text in 'UITextView', the height of 'UITableViewCell2' is automatically increased.

(2) When the height of 'UITableViewCell2' is increased, the height of 'UITableViewCell' is automatically increased accordingly.

I have implemented the case of (1) but not (2).

How should I implement it?

Comment: Why would you ever like to do like this? :)

Comment: While it is *possible* to embed text views inside table views inside table views, your design looks much better suited to a table view with multiple sections.

Comment: @Putte The designers on our team want this type of UI.

Comment: @DonMag Thank you for your advice. I'll try to use sections.

Comment: @DonMag 
How can I implement using 'section'? Can you explain more?

I do not come up with ideas.

Comment: @leka2002 - it's tough to say, without knowing exactly what your intent is. Are you planning on having a variable number of text views (in each of what you currently have labeled UITableView2)? Are you going to allow users to type multiple lines in each text view? Are you also going to have labels with the text views?

Comment: 1, Disable the scrolling of text view. 2, set textview height constraints then Implement textViewDidChange delegate and get textview content size and reinitilize height constraints. You may get expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to give this a try...

It using a single-section table view. Each cell contains a `UIStackView` that arranges the (variable) `UITextView`s.

No `@IBOutlet` or `@IBAction` or `prototype cell` connections... just assign a standard `UIViewController` custom class to `TableTextViewsViewController`:

```
//
//  TableTextViewsViewController.swift
//  Created by Don Mag on 3/10/20.
//

import UIKit

class TextViewsCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {

    let frameView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .clear

        v.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.5, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        v.layer.borderWidth = 1

        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.spacing = 8
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    let stackViewPadding: CGFloat = 8.0

    var textViewCosure: ((Int, String)->())?

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide

        contentView.addSubview(frameView)
        frameView.addSubview(stackView)

        // bottom constraint needs to be less than 1000 (required) to avoid auot-layout warnings
        let frameViewBottomConstrait = frameView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        frameViewBottomConstrait.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            frameView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            frameView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            frameView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            frameViewBottomConstrait,

            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameView.topAnchor, constant: stackViewPadding),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameView.leadingAnchor, constant: stackViewPadding),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameView.trailingAnchor, constant: -stackViewPadding),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameView.bottomAnchor, constant: -stackViewPadding),

        ])

    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        stackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach {
            $0.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    func fillData(_ strings: [String]) -> Void {
        strings.forEach {
            let v = UITextView()

            v.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
            v.isScrollEnabled = false

            // hugging and compression resistance set to required for cell expansion animation
            v.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
            v.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)

            v.text = $0

            // frame the text view
            v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            v.layer.borderWidth = 1

            v.delegate = self
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        guard let idx = stackView.arrangedSubviews.firstIndex(of: textView) else {
            fatalError("Shouldn't happen, but couldn't find the textView index")
        }
        textViewCosure?(idx, textView.text)
    }

}

class TableTextViewsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let topLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.text = "Top Label"
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    let tableView: UITableView = {
        let v = UITableView()

        v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        v.layer.borderWidth = 1

        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    var myData: [[String]] = [[String]]()
    var textViewsInRows: [Int] = [
        3, 4, 2, 6, 1, 4, 3,
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // generate some dummy data
        var i = 1
        textViewsInRows.forEach {
            var s: [String] = [String]()
            for j in 1...$0 {
                s.append("Table Row: \(i) TextView \(j)")
            }
            myData.append(s)
            i += 1
        }

        view.addSubview(topLabel)
        view.addSubview(tableView)

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            topLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            topLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            topLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),

        ])

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag

        tableView.register(TextViewsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TextViewsCell")

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextViewsCell", for: indexPath) as! TextViewsCell

        cell.fillData(myData[indexPath.row])

        cell.textViewCosure = { [weak self] idx, str in
            // update our data
            self?.myData[indexPath.row][idx] = str
            // update table view cell height
            self?.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self?.tableView.endUpdates()
        }

        return cell
    }

}
```

Result - red border is the tableView, green border is each cell's contentView, blue border is each textView:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Nesting table views may not be the ideal solution for this, but your UITableViewCell would need to estimate and measure the whole height of the embedded UITableView, and propagate changes up to the parent table.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be implemented like that.

Is there a better implementation?